# iOS Crashlytics crash report low memory

Tags: ios, memory, crashlytics

I received a crashlytics report with a Fatal Exception: NSUnknownKeyException and SIGABRT ABORT 0x0000000181c582e8. I checked my storyboard to make sure I had no bad outlets and I cannot reproduce the error. Because of this, I think the crash happened because of low memory. The device that it happened on had 14% Ram Free.

Here is the code on the line the report said the crash happened. "notes" is a key in an API response.

`if let notes = order.value(forKey: "notes") as? NSArray{`

Here is the stack trace

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are attempting to access `order`’s notes parameter, but in this case `order` is an NSCFBoolean (@YES or @NO, and an NSCFBoolean is basically an NSNumber). It doesn’t make sense for an NSCFBoolean or an NSNumber to have a notes parameter to access.

You are crashing because you attempted to access the non existent parameter. You may have assumed that `order` was a specific object, but somehow it ended up being something different. This can happen for a number of reasons, but in Swift likely boils down to the assumption that this variable was some other type.

I noticed that your code is in Swift, but the important part of your error reads better in Objective-C.

The error in your first screenshot is:

`Fatal Exception: NSUnknownKeyException
[<__NSCFBoolean 0x1b...> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key-value coding compliment for the key notes`

This is saying, send the `valueForUndefinedKey:` message (like a Swift function) to the Bool located at memory location: 0x1b...

In Objective-C, one may access an objects parameters through Key Value Observation (KVO) in this way.

In this case, however, it returns an exception, or basically an NSError that ends in a crash, because this key doesn’t exist.

I hope this helped explain the problem, it’s the best I could do without seeing your code directly. It doesn’t have to do with low memory, but instead is a KVO error where the system attempted to grab an object’s parameter that doesn’t exist.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So what would be the best way to go about safely accessing the notes parameter or checking if it exists? The API sends back a JSON object (order) with a notes parameter that is an array of notes. I thought I was safely checking if notes had a value?

Comment: Actually I just realized "order" is an array not an object. Can't believe I missed that. Now your answer makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @nsd32 I would recommend using Decodable for processing JSON, since you are using Swift. Very user-friendly and clean 

Comment: Yeah I have been planning on learning Decodable here soon. Do you happen to know why my current code works and I can't reproduce the crash?

Comment: Don’t expect APIs to always be consistent...for example, if an error is provided instead of the typical results, then the document structure won’t match what you have set up